# Having a unmapped Terms and Condition checkbox in a Symfony2 Form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, formbuilder

I've a registration form, which needs a checkbox for agreeing to the terms and conditions of the website. Since I dont want to save the value of the checkbox inside the user object, i've manually added a checkbox field which is not mapped to the data object.

When I submit the registration form without ticking the Terms checkbox, an error is displayed (Thats okay, since the checkbox is required). However the checkbox is now checked, which is unwanted. It should either be always unchecked (so that after every mistake in the form you have to check it again) or stay the way you've submitted it.

Below is the code (overwritten RegistrationController from the FOSUserBundle):

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();

    $form->setData($user);
    $form->add('xterms', 'checkbox', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'empty_data' => false,
        'required' => 'required',
        'label' => 'label.terms',
        'constraints' => array(new NotNull())));

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by doing the following:

1. Moved my code to the RegistrationFormType.php from the Registration Controller
2. Removed the properties empty_data, required and the NotNull Constraint
3. Used a Callback Constraint to check on the value of the field

*edit: I've marked this as a solution, because it's the way I've solved my problem. It doesn't directly address the problem however.

Answer (score 1):

you can add default value for your check box or any form field using the data attribute in the form element option array

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#data

```
$form->add('xterms', 'checkbox', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'empty_data' => false,
        'required' => 'required',
        'label' => 'label.terms',
        'data'=>false,
        'constraints' => array(new NotNull())));
```

hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried this, but the result is the same -> doesn't work, the checkbox will still be checked after submit